# If $|a_n| \to |a|$ and $|\frac{a_n}{|a_n|}-\frac{a}{|a|}|\to0$ can we conclude $a_n\to a$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If $|a_n| \to |a|$ and $|\frac{a_n}{|a_n|}-\frac{a}{|a|}|\to0$ can we conclude $a_n\to a$?

I am not sure. I tried various algebraic manipulations but could not figure it out. This problem came  up when trying to prove something, and I can prove it for normalized sequences, now i want to generalize it for all sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'll assume that $a,a_n\neq 0$, as otherwise the second quantity makes no sense.)

We see that
$$\frac{x}{|x|}=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x>0 \\ -1&\text{if }x<0.\end{cases}$$
So,
$$\left|\frac{a_n}{|a_n|}-\frac{a}{|a|}\right|$$
is $0$ if $a$ and $a_n$ lie on the same side of $0$, and $2$ otherwise. Your statement that this goes to $0$ means that $a_n$ lies on the same side of $0$ as $a$ for large $n$; can you see why this helps?

Answer (score 0):

$a_n=|a_n| \frac {a_n} {|a_n|} \to |a|\frac a {|a|} =a$ if $a \neq 0$. When $a=0$ it is obvious that $a_n \to 0$ since $|a_n| \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

As $| \frac{a_n}{|a_n|} - \frac{a}{|a|}| \to 0$, there exists $N_1$ such that $| \frac{a_n}{|a_n|} - \frac{a}{|a|}| < 1$ for any $n \ge N_1$. Note that $\frac{a_n}{|a_n|}, \frac{a}{|a|} \in \{\pm 1\}$. Thus, $| \frac{a_n}{|a_n|} - \frac{a}{|a|}| = 2$ if $\frac{a_n}{|a_n|} \ne \frac{a}{|a|}$. It follows that $\frac{a_n}{|a_n|} = \frac{a}{|a|}$ for any $n \ge N_1$.

Note that for any $n \ge N_1$, we have $|a_n| = a_n \cdot \frac{|a_n|}{a_n} = a_n \cdot \frac{|a|}{a}$. So, $||a_n| - |a|| = |a_n \cdot \frac{|a|}{a} - a \cdot \frac{|a|}{a}| = |a_n -a|$.

Given $\varepsilon > 0$.
As $|a_n| \to |a|$, there exists $N_2$ such that $||a_n| - |a|| < \varepsilon$ for any $n \ge N_2$. Let $N = \max\{N_1,N_2\}$. If $n \ge N$, then $|a_n - a| = ||a_n| - |a|| < \varepsilon$. Hence, $a_n \to a$.